# C++ Boost Concepts Deprecation Warning

Tags: c++, boost, warnings, deprecated, c++-concepts

The top of [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/concept_check/implementation.htm) page warns about deprecated a API. Where can I find its replacement then?

Comment: The page isn't warning that the API is deprecated, it's warning that the documentation describing the implementation is outdated and may refer to some deprecated functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code wasn't updated to newer model. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/concept_check/reference.htm) you can find all now supported functions.